# For loop with -eq in repeat-condition

Tags: xml, powershell, for-loop, powershell-5.0

Through all my searches, all examples of PowerShell's `for` looping has a *repeat-condition* of `-lt`, for example:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt 290; $i++) {$i}
```

But the following is not working:

```
for ($i=0; $i -eq 290; $i++) {$i}
```

Is this a known issue for PowerShell?  I'm trying to use an XML `.Count` (read-only) for my repeat-condition and `-lt` is not an option without adding a couple more lines of code of assigning a variable to the XML `.Count` and then incrementing said number to 1.  Then run the `for` loop with `-lt`.

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. A counting loop with an invariable condition where the loop variable must remain equal to a fixed value doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-3.0) (emphasis mine):

> **Syntax**
>
> The following shows the For statement syntax.
>
> ```
> for (>init>; <condition>; <repeat>)
> {<statement list>}
> ```
>
> […]
>
> The <condition> placeholder represents the portion of the For statement that resolves to a true or false Boolean value. Windows PowerShell evaluates the condition each time the For loop runs. If the statement is true, the commands in the command block run, and the statement is evaluated again. If the condition is still true, the commands in the statement list run again. **The loop is repeated until the condition becomes false.**

The condition in your second example is `$false` in the first iteration (`(0 -eq 290) ⇒ $false`), so the loop terminates immediately.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Think I was mistaken the For loop logic as a Do While...

I interpreted (0 -eq 290) was, repeat action by incrementing x++ starting with x (init) until x got to 290.

using -lt worked anyway including all data elements anyway, I forgot about the initial [0] is still counted as one

Answer (score 0):

I have never experienced this in PowerShell myself.  That said, I would definitely try `.GetType()` on both sides of the comparison operator to ensure you're comparing equal types.

Comment: Same value...  Quite odd..

$i.GetType()

IsPublic   IsSerial   Name   BaseType
True        True        Int32     System.ValueType                             

$test.CHECKLIST.STIGS.iSTIG.VULN.Count.GetType()

IsPublic   IsSerial   Name   BaseType                      
True        True        Int32     System.ValueType

Comment: Now this isn't pretty, but have you considered casting the variables to a string and comparing that way?

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I guess in this case I'm forced to casting.  Just doesn't make sense if they are the same type why -eq, -qe doesn't work but -lt does.

Comment: What is `GetType()` supposed to achieve? The "problem" here is that `for` loops simply don't work the way the OP wants them to.